# rate-limiter-flexible giving me an error Lua redis() command arguments must be strings or integers\

Tags: javascript, node.js, rate-limiting

I am applying rate limit using rate-limiter-flexible

```
const redis = require('redis');
const { RateLimiterRedis } = require('rate-limiter-flexible');
```

This is my code

```
  / Create a Redis client
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
  host: 'localhost', // Replace with your Redis server hostname
  port: 6379 // Replace with your Redis server port

});
// Define rate limiting options
const rateLimitOptions = {
  storeClient: redisClient,
  keyPrefix: 'rate-limiter:',
  points: 10, // Number of points a user can accumulate before getting rate limited
  duration: 60, // Time window in seconds
  blockDuration: 60 // Time in seconds for which a user will be blocked after getting rate limited
};

// Create a rate limiter instance
const rateLimiter = new RateLimiterRedis(rateLimitOptions);
// Express middleware to enforce rate limiting
const rateLimitMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  const ip = req.connection.remoteAddress; // Get the user's IP address
  const url = req.originalUrl; // Get the URL of the request
  const key = `${url}_${ip}`;// Use a combination of IP and URL as the key
  try {
    const rateLimiterRes = await rateLimiter.consume(key); // Pass the key and points as arguments
    next(); // Call next() to proceed to the next middleware or route handler
  } catch (rejRes) {
    // Handle rate limit exceeded
    const remainingTime = Math.ceil(rejRes.msBeforeNext / 1000);
```

It is giving me error on this line  Lua redis() command arguments must be strings or integers\

```
 const rateLimiterRes = await rateLimiter.consume(key); // Pass the key and points as arguments
```

My key I am passing is '/v2.0/json/login-user_::1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED on Feb 2024:

`rate-limiter-flexible` supports `node-redis` package. [Read about it in docs on WiKi](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Redis#redis-package).

OLD ANSWER:

Short answer: create Redis client with option `legacyMode: true`.

```js
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
  legacyMode: true,
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 6379
})
```

Description:
`node-redis` version 4 package had breaking changes, you can read about them [here](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/v3-to-v4.md).
`rate-limiter-flexible` doesn't support new `node-redis` package API, so you should use `legacyMode: true`. Alternatively, you can use `ioredis` package. Or contribute to `rate-limiter-flexible` to support `node-redis` v4+ API.